# How to stub Firebase property in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I am binding state with Firebase via [re-base](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) in my React component's `componentDidMount()` method. In my unit test for the component using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/), I'd like to remove that functionality so that it doesn't actually perform the binding. I'm at a loss of how to do it, do I:

1. Stub `this.base` somehow?
2. Stub `bindToState` somehow?
3. Move the binding functionality into another method and stub that method instead?

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.base = Rebase.createClass(config.firebaseUrl);
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.rebaseRef = this.base.bindToState('questions', {
    context: this,
    state: 'questions'
  });

  // other unrelated functionality below
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `reset: Removes all of the Firebase listeners and resets the singleton (for testing purposes).`? From the docs: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base#features